# Liferay Hooks: For overriding Liferay default can we specify as shown below?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6 for development .

I am trying to understand the concept of Liferay Hooks.  While googling I came across a Liferay Hooks example which specified a liferay-hook-xml with the following entry:

**liferay-hook.xml**

```xml
<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal-hook.properties</portal-properties>
    <service>
        <service-type>com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService</service-type>
        <service-impl> com.integratingstuff.liferay.hooks.CustomUserLocalServiceImpl</service-impl>
    </service>
</hook>
```

Could anybody please tell me what exactly does this mean?  My understanding is that the UserLocalService class of Liferay has been overridden to use CustomUserLocalServiceImpl.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My mind `<service-impl>` override the `UserLocalServiceWrapper`. With this concept you can add some functions to liferay default design.

see: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/overriding-a-portal-service